# get value from <input> which is in a <li> and append value into <li> as a link (a)

Tags: jquery, input, append, each

I tried to get the value from each input in an li and append the value into the label as a link. Here is my code. Something is obviously wrong. How can I fix this?

```js
$("ul li label").each(function() {
 var $link = $("ul li label input").val(); 
 $(this).append('<span><a target="_blank" href="' + $link + '"> PDF-Download</a></span>');
});
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/first.pdf" />first</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/second.pdf" />second</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/third.pdf" />third</label></li>
</ul>
```

At the end it should look like:

```html
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/first.pdf" />first<a target="_blank" href="/first.pdf"> PDF-Download</a></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/second.pdf" />second<a target="_blank" href="/second.pdf"> PDF-Download</a></label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/third.pdf" />third<a target="_blank" href="/third.pdf"> PDF-Download</a></label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var $link = $("ul li label input").val();` is where the issue is. You need to use an instance of `this` to get the content from the corresponding `input`

```
var $link = $(this).find("input").val();
```

Comment: Great! Works perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd iterate over the inputs, referring to their value with `this` and add the link after with:

```js
$("ul li label input").each(function() {
 var $link = $(this).val(); 
 $(this).parent().after(' <span><a target="_blank" href="' + $link + '"> PDF-Download</a></span>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/first.pdf" />first</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/second.pdf" />second</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="/third.pdf" />third</label></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
var $link = $("ul li label input").val();
```

is getting the value of the first match every time.

Try this:

```
$("ul li label").each(function() {
    var $link = $(this).find("input").val();    
    $(this).append('<span><a target="_blank" href="' + $link + '"> PDF-Download</a></span>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some working code. You weren't referencing the inputs that are owned by the selector. The 'ele' parameter in the function is an array of the labels that were selected. You can then use it in your val() method to make sure you match up the inputs with the correct values. See below.

```
   $(function() {
    $('ul li label').each(function(i, ele) {
            var $link = $("input", ele).val();
        $(ele).append('<span><a target="_blank" href="' + $link + '"> PDF-Download</a></span>');
    });
});
```